# Access multidimensional array elements using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

How can I access an element of the N-dimensional array using pointers? i.e What can I use instead of `a[i][j]...[k]`?

For example, I tried doing the following, but this doesn't work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int n1 = 5, n2 = 5, n3 = 5;
    int array[n1][n2][n3];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    for (int k = 0; k < n3; k++)
        array[i][j][k] = n1*n2*n3;

    cout << array[1][2][4]<<endl;
    cout << *(*array + n1 + n2 * 2 + 4);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u post here your code?

Comment: Won't `*(*a + i * n + j)` cause undefined behavior for `i > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting

> The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is that **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**.

From this, I can say that all of the followings are equivalent:

```
a[i][j][k]
(*(a + i))[j][k]
(*((*(a + i)) + j))[k]
(*((*((*(a + i)) + j)) + k))
```

Note: The added code is C++, not C. For C++, [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.2.1 Subscripting says that:

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`